# R: Shiny: How to align a gvisTable to the center in shinyapp

Tags: css, r, shiny

looking in the shiny group on Google:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/J8C2CnFOTOM

I've found a solution, however i just know the basics of HTML and a little bit of CSS. How can i implement the solution within my code?

I need to put the gvisTable to the center. I put the code directly to the htmlOutput function, as an argument but get an error:

**Note: this is the only change i've done to my code.

```
 tabPanel('Ikasa Adwords MotionChart',
                   br(),
                   htmlOutput("resumen",
                              tags$style(type="text/css",
                                         HTML("#summary>div { margin: 0 auto; }")
                              )),
                   br(),
                   br(),
```

Error:

```
ERROR: argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Original ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).


# Define the overall UI
shinyUI(

  # Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
  fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    br(),
    br(),
    br(),
    titlePanel("Ikasa Adwords"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    br(),
    br(),
    sidebarLayout(      

      # Define the sidebar with one input



      sidebarPanel(
        dateRangeInput("dates", label = h3("Date range"),
                       start = "2015-01-01", end = "2015-02-15")

      ),



      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(

          tabPanel('Ika MotionChart',
                   br(),
                   htmlOutput("resumen",
                              tags$style(type="text/css",
                                         HTML("#summary>div { margin: 0 auto; }")
                              )),
                   br(),
                   br(),

                   htmlOutput("motionchart")

        )

      )
    )
  )))
```

Comment: Guess [`htmlOutput`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/htmlOutput.html) doesn't accept a second argument as a tag in this case  `tags$style`. You can just mention inline true or false. Also in your style tag you are saying `#summary` and there is no div with id #summary in your code. And to make it centered you need to give width to the element along with `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting the `css` directly on the table, using a `tag$style`.

For example:

```
tabPanel('Ika MotionChart',
                   br(),
                   htmlOutput("resumen"),
                   tags$style(HTML("#resumen table{ 
                                  margin: auto;
                                   }")),
                   br(),
                   br(),

                   htmlOutput("motionchart")
                   tags$script(HTML("
                        var p = document.getElementById('motionchart')
                        $(p).attr('align', 'center');"))

          )
```

The `css` sets the right and left margins to `auto` to all `table` in the elements that have the `resumen` id. The right and left margin around the `table` should be split equally resulting in a centered table.

For the `motionChart`, the actual chart is an `embed` element so you can change the alignment by setting the `align` attribute using javascript.

In chrome, with some WorldPhone data I get this:

[image]

Comment: it works. Please, may you add an example for a motion chart. Acording to the info in this page: [link]https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart ... i did this code:  `tags$style(HTML("#motionchart motionchart{
                                  margin-left: auto;
                                  margin-right: auto;
                                   }")
                   ),
                   htmlOutput("motionchart")` But it is not working.